# C# use class in different function

Tags: c#, class

I made an new WPF App. I created a new class called Auto. In `public MainWindow()` I made a new entry to Auto:

```
Auto firstcar = new Auto();
```

Then on the same code page I have the function:

```
private void btnKm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Here I want to also enter Property's to firstcar. How can I do that?

On the internet I found `Auto firstcar = firstcar;` however it says firstcar is unassigned.

Comment: Read about variable scope. If you want multiple methods in your class to be able to access the same object, declare it at the class level: `public class MyClass { private Auto firstcar = new Auto(); private void btnKm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { firstcar.Color = Color.Red; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your question the variable "firstcar" is a local variable to the constructor (public MainWindow()).

You should make it availabe to your class as a Field or Property. That way it is possible to change Properties in other methods of your class

```
Auto _firstcar;

public MainWindow()
{
    _firstcar = new Auto();
}

private void btnKm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _firstCar.Doors = 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

i did not get your question properly. i believe , you have access problem.

you can create firstcar  object as class variable, so that it will be visible to all event handlers in your code behind.

```
Auto _firstcar = new Auto();

private void btnKm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _firstCar.YourProperty= Value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted :) Thanks!